# Syntax to overload () parentheses operator in C++

Tags: c++, header, overloading, operator-keyword, parentheses

I am a newbie at C++ and was given this assignment.  I have to use this header file, from which I have provided the relevant excerpt.  The class name is PayoffAsianCall.

```
PayoffAsianCall(double strike);
virtual double operator()(std::vector<double> & spot) const;
virtual ~PayoffAsianCall(){}
```

I want to assign some stuff to the operator in my main file
I have been using

```
    PayoffAsianCall &PayoffAsianCall::virtual double operator()(std::vector<double> & spot) const { do stuff here}
```

but this has not been working.  Can someone explain to me the correct syntax please?

Comment: [This should be covered early in any non-fraudulent C++ text.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It´s always hard to gain some ground for beginners and c++ isn´t that easy to tame. So here are some hints for you:

We start with your try

> PayoffAsianCall &PayoffAsianCall::virtual double operator()(std::vector & spot) const { do stuff here}

First: The first thing to note is the return type, you say the return type is

> PayoffAsianCall &

btw. you should really pay attention to the position of the `&`. In this case it means `referenece` and its PayoffAsianCall Reference so it should have been PayoffAsianCall& and not PayoffAsianCall &.

But anyway: in the class definition you say the return value is `double` so it should be `double`:

> double PayoffAsianCall::virtual double operator()(std::vector & spot) const { do stuff here}

thats already much better. Now we need the operator name, since it is a class member the name includes the class name `virtual` and `double` have nothing to do with the name, `virtual` is reserved for use in the class definition itself so there is no room for it here and double is already taken care of. So we now have:

> double PayoffAsianCall::operator()(std::vector & spot) const { do stuff here}

That´s all. I would recommend, as mentioned before, to correctly place the `&`. It´s not a std::vector reference-spot but a std::vector-reference spot:

> double PayoffAsianCall::operator()(std::vector& spot) const { do stuff here}

done.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful.  I am a graduate student and for some reason, the professors think that it is productive to just have people try to figure this out using Google.  I'd also appreciate a recommendation for a good reference text.  Literally started learning C++ around 24 hours ago.  Thanks Again!

Comment: @AliceinWonderLand If the answer was useful please do not forget to accept the answer.  A book recommendation is not as easy as it sounds but my bet would be "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" by the creator of c++ Bjarne Stroustrup. The first half is easy stuff but pace increases fast. So its suited to get a start as well as to get some more advanced questions answered after you gained some experience.